# Как получить ссылку при нажатии на кнопку и перейти по ней?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://example.com/" data-quantity="1" class=" add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="1111" data-product_sku="222" aria-label="Выберите опции" rel="nofollow">Выберите параметры</a>
  <!-- plugin version: 2.4.3; mode: show_add_to_card -->
  <button type="button" data-value-product-id="225011" class="add-to-card-one" id="custom-order-button-225011">Купить в один клик</button>
</div>
```

Если строка с `class="add_to_cart_button"` содержит "Выберите параметры",
то при нажатии на button `class="add-to-card-one"` получить url от строки выше (кнопки выберите параметры) и перейти по этому url.

Помогите пожалуйста решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-card-one', function() {
    let href = $(this).prev('a.add_to_cart_button').attr('href');    
    if (href !== undefined) {
        console.log(href);
        //location.href = href;  // <--- надо раскоментировать
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="1111" data-product_sku="222" aria-label="Выберите опции" rel="nofollow">Выберите параметры</a>
<!-- plugin version: 2.4.3; mode: show_add_to_card -->


<button type="button" data-value-product-id="225011" class="add-to-card-one" id="custom-order-button-225011">Купить в один клик</button>
```

Comment: А как добавить условие? Если содержит текст то выполнить весь ваш код

Comment: Какой текст? Где именно текст? Ориентир на текст - не верное решение. Правильно ориентироваться на атрибуты, классы и пр.

Comment: Если у строки есть класс .product_type_variable то в таком случае запускать скрипт, как сделать такое условие?

Comment: У какой строки? какой запускать скрипт? ничего не понятно

Comment: <a href="https://example.com/" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="1111" data-product_sku="222" aria-label="Выберите опции" rel="nofollow">Выберите параметры</a> 

Если тут не будет класса add_to_cart_button то скрипт не выполнять

Comment: @ВалиевАртур в *Jquery* есть метод **[hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** - примените его

Comment: Вы извините я в синтаксисе очень плохо разбираюсь.

вот что я набросал но не работает:

 jQuery(document).on('click', '.awooc-custom-order-button', function() {
  if(jQuery('.add_to_cart_button').hasClass('.add_to_cart_button')){
   
   
 
    alert('У этого блока есть класса product_type_variable');
 
    }
 
 else{
   let href = jQuery(this).prev('.add_to_cart_button').attr('href');
   location.href = href;  // <--- надо раскоментировать
     
    }
});

Comment: @ВалиевАртур чуть изменил код. проще так. искать элемент ближайший с классом. если не найден - ничего не делать

Comment: Всё, круто спасибо большое!

Comment: @ВалиевАртур можно галочку слева от ответу ткнуть)